# Android: strange button layout with Ice Cream

Tags: android, image, button, background

I built a layout with this custom bar at the top:

[image]

The bar illustrated, contains three example buttons (one at left and two at right), with an image background (ic_delete) contained in the default android drawable.

This is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_top_bar" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_swype_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:text="" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bar1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_swype_left"
            android:maxWidth="1dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/status_bar_item_app_background" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/municipality"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bar1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bar2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Some Text"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bar2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:maxWidth="1dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_menu"
            android:src="@android:drawable/status_bar_item_app_background" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bar3"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bar3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:maxWidth="1dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_swype_right"
            android:src="@android:drawable/status_bar_item_app_background" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_swype_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:text="" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout ... >

        <ListView .... />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

All is right when I try my app in devices with Android version < 4.0 (API 14), as shown below:

[image: Bar in Android verion < 4.0 (API 14 )]

but in devices with Android version >= 4.0 (API 14, 15, 16), the width dimensions of buttons are strange:

[image: Bar in Android version >= 4.0 (API 14, 15, 16)]

what wrong?

Comment: Try replacing `Button` with `ImageButton`

Comment: @GrahamSmith: no, it isn't an action bar

Comment: Try changing to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` `in TextView`

Comment: i try to use ImageButton instead Button as suggested by @Waqas and IT WORKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the size of the android system images change beetween those versions, in particular i mean the width **@android:drawable/ic_delete**, try using a custom image you make